# Java Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I have been asked this question in an interview.

can anyone explain it.

```
public class A{

     public void show(List <String>list1,List<Integer>lists2){...}

     public void show(List <Integer>list1,List<String>lists2){...}
}
public class B{
 public static void main(..){
    A a=new A();
    List<String> list1;
    List<Integer>lists2;
    a.show(list1,lists2);
     }
   }
```

I said 2 function would be called.. but when i worte in neatbeans it gave error of same name function been called...???
why so isnt overloading concept used here???

Comment: Your code won't compile. Both your `show` methods have the same erasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Generics are enforced at compile time, but the type of the Collection is erased, and what you're left with is a duplicate method.  In an IDE, you would get some message about "same type erasure."

Here's a good discussion about it that I enjoyed:

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/generics.html

Answer (score 6):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the arguments of the method will become `List`.

```
public void show(List list1, List list2);
public void show(List list1, List list2);
```

Thus becoming invalid code.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove "public" from one of your class declaration (actually from class A) .

Second, the compiler is reading the parameter as `show(list, list)`, so it is giving you the same method and there is no overloading occurring here.
As both parameters are `show(list, list)`.

Remember, generics are used to distinguish the object type not the return type.

Hope it works.